# Did Batman ever tell Superman "the last time when you really inspired anyone was when you were dead"?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

I recently saw a quote online where Batman a.k.a Bruce Wayne says the following to Superman:

> ***If you tell them to fight, they will fight. But they need to be inspired. And let's face it "Superman", the last time when you really inspired anyone was when you were dead.***

Has Batman ever said this, or anything similar to this, to Superman in the comics? If yes, what story-line (comic issue) did this occur in?

Comment: Have you ever googled that sentence? [It can be found online](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Infinite_Crisis)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer argh, 12 seconds before I could finish my answer.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer well, I guess I should have googled it. My bad.

Comment: Argh! Batman is Bruce Wayne? Dude, spoilers!  :)

Comment: @Paul Wait, superheroes can have secret identities?  Spoilers!

Comment: @Paul - ...nope, definitely not true.  100% fake news.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Infinite Crisis #1 (2005)

Googling just the first two lines of the quote took me to [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Batman_(comics)#Infinite_Crisis), which quotes the exact same line with a slightly different amount of punctuation.

> Everyone looks up to you. *They listen to you. If you tell them to fight, they'll fight. But they need to be inspired. And let's face it "Superman"... the last time you really inspired anyone -- was when you were dead.*

According to another [Wikiquote page](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Infinite_Crisis#Batman), it appears to come from Issue #1

The relevant page can be found below:

[image: Page from the comic with the quote]

Comment: [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/185850/68872) had found the image a couple dozen seconds before me, although this isn't clear from my edit history, which is supposedly non-existent.

Comment: Who is the character in the 3rd-to-last panel with the blue vest?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the context here?

Comment: @DavidStarkey I believe it is [Uncle Sam](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Uncle_Sam_(New_Earth))

Comment: @DavidK For context check the link at the bottom of my answer, you can read the full comic.

Comment: @Edlothiad - If you edit a question within a minute or two of the original post, it doesn't record it as an edit. Current timeline is 5 minutes according to [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Answer (score 30):

This comes from [Infinite Crisis Vol 1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Crisis_Vol_1_1).

> **Everyone** looks up to you. They listen to you.
>   If you tell them to fight, they'll ***fight***.
>
> But they need to be **inspired**. And let's face it, **"Superman"**...
>   ...the last time you really inspired **anyone**--
>
> ...was when you were **dead**.

[image: Infinite Crisis Vol 1]